# How to use authentication token in NSURLRequest

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, restful-authentication, nsurlrequest

I'm using a service with REST API, which provides me an authentication token as the response for the sign in POST request.

Now for authentication on every request i need to send that token with the request.
How to use this token with every request i send to server ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you need from your question, but here is a guess.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rest.u.rl/do/this"];
NSString *header = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",token]; //format as needed
[request setValue:header forHTTPHeaderField:@"TokenFieldName"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
```

And to do this for every *other* one, do a `if (i % 2 == 0)` or something to that effect.